# adding column in Oracle SQL table that is random sample from another column/table

Tags: sql, oracle, random, sample

I have a preexisting table (MYORIGTABLE) in SQL and I would like to add a column which is a random sample from a column in another table (RANDNUM10). The other table is a 1 column sample of random numbers I've predetermined and would like to sample from; column name is RANDVAL. I've tried the following

`select 
(select randval from
 (SELECT randval 
 FROM  RANDNUM10
 ORDER BY dbms_random.value) 
 where rownum=1) as mynum
from MYORIGTABLE`

But unfortunately this just gives me the same random number which was sampled from RANDNUM10 repeated for the entire length of MYORIGTABLE. How can I perform the sampling so that every line of MYORIGTABLE gets a newly generated sample?

Thanks,
Christie

Comment: When you say you would like to add a column, what exactly do you mean? An `UPDATE` statement as in @Littlefoot's answer might work, while a `SELECT` might not.

Comment: You need to give a clearer explanation of what you are trying to do. You said you want to ADD A COLUMN but then you show a SELECT statement where you just select values from a single column in a table. What do you mean by ADD A COLUMN - where? In the MYORIGTABLE table? Or only in the result set of a SELECT query (which obviously will select other columns from MYORIGTABLE also)?

Comment: Also, when you say "a random sample", is that with replacement, or without? If you don't know what that means: if the random numbers are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 - then a "random sample of three numbers WITH REPLACEMENT" may be (3, 4, 3). WITHOUT REPLACEMENT does not allow duplicates. If your requirement is WITHOUT REPLACEMENT, you must guarantee that the second table has more rows than the first - is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
select (select randval
        from (SELECT randval 
              FROM  RANDNUM10
              ORDER BY dbms_random.value
             ) 
        where rownum = 1
      ) as mynum
from MYORIGTABLE;
```

A common problem with database optimizers -- in this situation -- that that it optimizes away the multiple calls to the subquery.  It ends up replacing the subquery with one call.

One way around this is to use a correlated subquery.  For this, I would recommend removing one level of nesting:

```
select (select max(randval) keep (dense_rank first order by dbms_rnadom.value)
        from randnum10
        where myorigtable.id is not null -- or whatever
      ) as mynum
from MYORIGTABLE;
```

I think this will work so the subquery is called 10 times, although a more complex correlation clause might be needed.

Comment: But if you try something like this, it might: `where myorigtable.id > 0` (in place of `is not null`)

Comment: Wrong approach anyway - if the base table has, for example, 200,000 rows and the random numbers table has 3 million rows, the correlated subquery will need to generate 3 million random values and select the first one, 200,000 times. Exceptionally inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps?

Test case:

```
SQL> create table myorigtable (id number);

Table created.

SQL> create table randnum10 (randval number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into myorigtable select level from dual connect by level <= 10;

10 rows created.

SQL> insert into randnum10 select round(dbms_random.value(1, 100)) from dual connect by level <= 10;

10 rows created.

SQL> alter table myorigtable add randval number;

Table altered.
```

Update:

```
SQL> update myorigtable m set
  2    m.randval = (select x.randval
  3                 from (select randval, row_number() over (order by randval) rn
  4                       from randnum10
  5                      ) x
  6                 where x.rn = m.id
  7                );

10 rows updated.

SQL> select * from myorigtable;

        ID    RANDVAL
---------- ----------
         1          5
         2         18
         3         29
         4         31
         5         31
         6         62
         7         66
         8         87
         9         94
        10         98

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: This is the right approach, but it depends on the base table having an ID column with values 1, 2, 3, ..., N. In real life that may or may not be the case - but that is not very hard to fix. The bigger issue is that you are not assigning a "random sample" of values from the random numbers table - you are assigning the N smallest values. That can be fixed too with a bit more work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach. I assume your `RANDNUM10` table has many rows (more rows than `MYORIGTABLE`), you want to sample the random numbers without replacement (select DISTINCT random values from `RANDNUM10`) - and therefore the random numbers table has enough rows - at least as many as `MYORIGTABLE` - and you need to add the column to the result set of a `SELECT` query, rather than to the stored table. (If you need to store the result in an additional column, then you must first add the column if it doesn't already exist, and use the `SELECT` query below in an `UPDATE` statement.)

The strategy is simple: associate arbitrary row numbers to the smaller table (with values 1, 2, ..., N where N is the row count), and associate random row numbers to the rows in the random numbers table. Both can be done with `ROW_NUMBER()...` - the first one can be ordered by `NULL` since all the randomness we need will come from the other table's row numbers anyway. Then JOIN the two tables on the row number thus added to both tables.

For illustration I created `MYORIGTABLE` as a copy of `SCOTT.EMP`, selecting only a few columns from that table. Here's what the query looks like, and the output using that as `MYORIGTABLE`.

**Setup**:

```
create table myorigtable as select empno, ename, job, deptno from scott.emp;

create table randnum10 ( randval ) as
  select dbms_random.value() from dual connect by level <= 1000;
```

**Query and output**:

```
select a.empno, a.ename, a.job, a.deptno, b.randval
from   (
         select empno, ename, job, deptno, row_number() over (order by null) as rn
         from   myorigtable
       ) a
       inner join
       (
         select randval, row_number() over (order by dbms_random.value()) as rn
         from   randnum10
       ) b
       on a.rn = b.rn
;

EMPNO  ENAME       JOB        DEPTNO     RANDVAL
-----  ----------  --------- -------  ----------
 7369  SMITH       CLERK          20  .991998901
 7499  ALLEN       SALESMAN       30  .448133242
 7521  WARD        SALESMAN       30  .136242235
 7566  JONES       MANAGER        20  .443347421
 7654  MARTIN      SALESMAN       30  .836931008
 7698  BLAKE       MANAGER        30  .361437867
 7782  CLARK       MANAGER        10  .433786615
 7788  SCOTT       ANALYST        20  .285173363
 7839  KING        PRESIDENT      10  .063840361
 7844  TURNER      SALESMAN       30  .825888729
 7876  ADAMS       CLERK          20  .818415041
 7900  JAMES       CLERK          30  .150180080
 7902  FORD        ANALYST        20  .442389099
 7934  MILLER      CLERK          10  .086995415
```